# changing textlabel and qthread pyqt

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer

I write some GUI with qt designer. This script is generated with qt designer and I wrote  class mythread:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import time
import socket
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class mythread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            TCP_IP = 
            TCP_PORT = 
            s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
            s.send('GLST\r\n')
            glst = s.recv(1024)
            if glst:
                s.send('GLSC\r\n')
                glsc = s.recv(1024)
                print glst,glsc
            s.close()
            time.sleep(0.1)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 221, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color:rgb(48, 48, 48)"))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 40, 221, 31))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color:rgb(48, 48, 48)"))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.label, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textChanged(QString)")), self.mythread)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600; color:#ffffff;\">co:</span></p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600; color:#ffffff;\">co:</span></p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In class mythread I have function run which is make connection to server and then send two commands on them. This function receives some data(glst,glsc) and now I want to see dynamically this data (glst,glsc) with while loop in textlabel in GUI.

But I dont know how connect thread to gui-textlabel.

Thanks for any ideas. Johny

Here is script with supplement from coments

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import time
import socket

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

 class mythread(QtCore.QThread):
     def __init__(self):
         QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

     def run(self):
        while True:
             TCP_IP = 
             TCP_PORT = 
             s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
             s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
             s.send('GLSC\r\n')
             glsc = s.recv(1024)
             print glsc[:9]
             self.setLog(glsc[:9])
             if glsc:
                 s.send('GLST\r\n')
                 glst = s.recv(1024)
                 print glst
                 self.setLog(glst)
             s.close()
             time.sleep(0.1)


     def setLog (self, text):
         self.emit(SIGNAL("log(QString)"), QtCore.QString(text))


 class Ui_MainWindow(object):

     def setupUi(self,MainWindow):
         self.mythread = mythread()
         MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
         MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
         self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
         self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
         self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
         self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 221, 31))
         self.label.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color:rgb(48, 48, 48)"))
         self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
         self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
         self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 40, 221, 31))
         self.label_2.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color:rgb(48, 48, 48)"))
         self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
         MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
         self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
         self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
         self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
         MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
         self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
         self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))

         MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
         self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
         QtCore.QObject.connect(self.mythread, QtCore.SIGNAL("log(QString)"), self.label.setText)
         QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

     def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
         MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
         self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600; color:#ffffff;\"></span></p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
         self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600; color:#ffffff;\"></span></p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))




 if __name__ == "__main__":
     import sys
     app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
     MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
     ui = Ui_MainWindow()
     ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
     MainWindow.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LAST EDITED : 12 / 8 / 2014 9 : 01 Refactor code**

I suggest you implement by inheritance class `QtGui.QMainWindow`, please see my refactor code;

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import time
import socket

class QMyThread (QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(QtCore.QThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
            TCP_PORT = 23
            mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            mySocket.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
            mySocket.send('GLSC\r\n')
            glsc = mySocket.recv(1024)
            print glsc[:9]
            self.setLog1(glsc[:9])
            if glsc:
                mySocket.send('GLST\r\n')
                glst = mySocket.recv(1024)
                print glst
                self.setLog2(glst)
            mySocket.close()
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def setLog1 (self, text):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('log1(QString)'), QtCore.QString(text))

    def setLog2 (self, text):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('log2(QString)'), QtCore.QString(text))

class QMyMainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.myInit()

    def myInit (self):
        self.mythread = QMyThread(self)
        self.setObjectName('MainWindow')
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName('centralwidget')
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 221, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet('color:rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color:rgb(48, 48, 48);')
        self.label.setObjectName('label')
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 40, 221, 31))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet('color:rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color:rgb(48, 48, 48);')
        self.label_2.setObjectName('label_2')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName('menubar')
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName('statusbar')
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.setWindowTitle('Main Windows')

        self.connect(self.mythread, QtCore.SIGNAL('log1(QString)'), self.label.setText)
        self.connect(self.mythread, QtCore.SIGNAL('log2(QString)'), self.label_2.setText)
        self.mythread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMyMainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**LAST EDITED : 12 / 8 / 2014 7 : 34 Fix error 'connect not found'**

I same idea to your main widget to QThread, connect it with `SIGNAL` back to main widget;

**Main widget**

```
.
.
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    .
    .
    self.mythread = mythread()
    .
    .
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.mythread, QtCore.SIGNAL("log(QString)"), self.label.setText)
    .
    .
```

**QThread**

```
class mythread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            TCP_IP = 
            TCP_PORT = 
            s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
            s.send('GLST\r\n')
            glst = s.recv(1024)
            self.setLog(glst)
            if glst:
                s.send('GLSC\r\n')
                glsc = s.recv(1024)
                self.setLog(glsc)
                print glst,glsc
            s.close()
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def setLog (self, text):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("log(QString)"), QtCore.QString(text))
```

---

Regards,

Comment: Thank you very much. But when I added your script lines to my whole script I got AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'connect'. I dont understand what is it.

Comment: Sorry, error is I think your inheritance QWidget or QMainWindows, please see my last edited answer.

Comment: I added to main post script with your script lines...but I have again error AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'mythread'

Comment: Please define 'self.mythread' in 'Ui_MainWindow'; self.mythread = mythread()

Comment: Ok...Look at my first post pls-I edited it...now i see GUI with text label but nothing more...It seem that the thread dont work...should it not start?

Comment: OK, your have to understand QThread must call 'QThread.start (self, Priority priority = QThread.InheritPriority)' to start it.

Ummm, I suggest your implement by inheritance 'QtGui.QMainWindow', Please read my last edited answer.

And If you have any else, please move this to chat. (It too long. . .) Thanks

Comment: Thank you very I understand now...Script is running...Thanks